# SQL Specific Order

Tags: sql, postgresql

Given the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.iswinner, i.name 
  FROM nominees n, institutions i
  WHERE n.iid = i.iid and n.filmname = '127 Hours' 
  ORDER BY name
```

I get the output:

```
iswinner    name

NULL    academy awards
NULL    baftas
NULL    critics' choice awards
NULL    golden globes
NULL    screen actors guild
NULL    writers guild of america
```

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to order this output in a more specific manner. The order I am looking for is to list first 'academy awards', then 'golden globes' then anything with a 'guild' in its name, and finally anything else alphabetically. So therefore the output I'm looking for is more along the lines of this:

```
iswinner    name

NULL    academy awards
NULL    golden globes
NULL    screen actors guild
NULL    writers guild of america
NULL    bafta
NULL    critics' choice awards
```

Is there a way to do such a thing? I believe I should use something like CASE, but I couldn't seem to figure out the correct syntax for it. Thanks for any help.

Comment: This can get you close: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_field

Comment: Or have another "dictionary" table to make it more flexible and order by its ID

Comment: @joeframbach: PostgreSQL != MySQL and `field` is MySQL-specific.

Comment: Oops not paying attention. Sorry!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a way to do something like this and just like you thought, you can do this with a CASE statement.  Something like the following should do the trick:

```
SELECT
    DISTINCT n.iswinner,
    i.name,
    CASE
        WHEN i.name = 'academy awards' THEN 1
        WHEN i.name = 'golden globes' THEN 2
        WHEN i.name like '%guild%' THEN 3
        ELSE 4
    END AS Order
FROM nominees n, institutions i
WHERE n.iid = i.iid and n.filmname = '127 Hours'
ORDER BY
    Order,
    i.name
```

So, to give you a little more information on what is being done here.  In the ORDER clause, we're ordering by a CASE statement.  Basically, based upon what the i.name field is, we are assigning an integer number to order by.  academy awards is assigned 1, golden globes is assigned 2, anything that contains 'guild' is assigned 3, and anything else is assigned 4.  So we first order by this CASE statement (which gives the specific ordering you want) and then order by the name field which will satisfy your the second requirement of ordering anything else by name (which we previously assigned the value of 4 in the CASE statement for ordering).

I hope this makes sense to you.

Same query using GROUP BY rather than DISTINCT:

```
SELECT
    n.iswinner,
    i.name
FROM nominees n, institutions i
WHERE n.iid = i.iid and n.filmname = '127 Hours'
GROUP BY 
    n.iswinner,
    i.isname
ORDER BY
    CASE
        WHEN i.name = 'academy awards' THEN 1
        WHEN i.name = 'golden globes' THEN 2
        WHEN i.name like '%guild%' THEN 3
        ELSE 4
    END,
    i.name
```

Comment: The explanation makes complete sense thank you. However, when attempting to implement this, I get the following error:
"for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list"

Comment: Seems like that error is saying that you have to include all of the columns in the ORDER BY in the SELECT query when using the DISTINCT keyword.  Try adding the CASE statement as a column in the SELECT clause.  I will update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Hmm, that certainly does seem to fix the issue, but does add an extra column to my table, is there anyway to avoid this? Other than simply making it a subquery and selecting from that.

Comment: Instead of using DISTINCT, you can try using the GROUP BY clause.  Let me write the same query with a GROUP BY instead.

Comment: That makes a great deal of sense, and gives me the results I'm looking for. Thank you for the help and detailed explanations.

Comment: Do you really need the CASE expression in the ORDER BY clause? Wouldn't it be sufficient to put it in the SELECT column list and include that column in the ORDER BY?

Comment: @WarrenT - I think you're correct.  You can order by the "Order" column that we created using the CASE keyword.  I'll edit the code to reflect that.

Answer (score 3):

```
order by
        case 
        when name = 'academy awards' then 1
        when name = 'golden globes' then 2
        when name like  '%guild%' then 3
        else 4
        end
,       name
```

Comment: For the third and 4th case, will those be listed in alphabetical order themselves as well? If so this seems to be exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No need for a `case` clause. [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!12/fac70/1)

```
select *
from (
    select distinct n.iswinner, i.name
    from nominees n, institutions i
    where n.iid = i.iid and n.filmname = '127 Hours'
) s
order by
    name != 'academy awards',
    name != 'golden globes',
    name not like '%guild%',
    name
```

`false` orders before `true`